# Centos x86_64 PHP 5.2.14 SQLITE missing? (WEBTATIC repo)

Tags: php, sqlite, centos, x86-64

i allready updated php on my server to version 5.2.14 from webtatic repository (http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/). But i can't find SQLITE.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with webtatic...

To see what version of sqlite is installed on the machine, execute the following command as root or sudo

```
yum info sqlite
```

I am guessing you mean that php can't access sqlite?

What I had to do to was install the php sqlite part. For whatever reason, it seems that centos gutted it out of their php distro. What I did to install sqlite for php was download the version of php that is currently installed on the server.

```
wget http://www.php.net/get/php-5.2.14.tar.gz/from/a/mirror
```

Build the sqlite extension

```
tar zxvf php-5.2.14.tar.gz
cd php-5.2.14/ext/sqlite
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Add sqlite.so to php
Create the file (likely location, you should see other .ini files in the same folder)

```
vi /etc/php.d/sqlite.ini
```

Press 'i' for insert mode and add the following line

```
extension=sqlite.so
```

Hit the [esc] key, and type :wq to 'w'rite and 'q'uite VI

Then do an apache restart

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

running a php page with phpinfo(); at the top will show you if you now have sqlite installed.

Comment: I have the same issue - may you show more details on how to `Add sqlite.so to php` as instructed?

Comment: The steps provided are key presses to get the job done. A google search may be able to provide more details if you need something more specific.